# ReactJS adding onClick handler into element given an HTML string

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm given an HTML string from an API:

```
<div><h1>something</h1><img src="something" /></div>
```

I would like to add an `onClick` handler onto the `img` tag. I thought about using regex replace, but it's highly advised against.

I'm new to React... how would you go about solving this problem?

Any links or pointing into the right direction would be highly appreciated!

## EDIT

Is there a way to add a listener to all anchor tags in a react friendly way? I'm thinking then I can just check the anchor tag's children, and if there's an image element, then I can run my code block.

Answer (score 1):

Can you update your API to return JSON instead of HTML? JSON is easier to manipulate and you can create react elements on the fly, for example, let's assume your API returns this:

```
{ 
  component: 'div',
  children: [
    { component: 'h1', text: 'Something here' },
    { component: 'img', src: 'something.jpg' },
  ],
}
```

If you have that kind of response is very easy to create React elements at run time, you can also add events when creating these components, for example:

```
class DynamicContent extends PureComponent {
  onImageClick = () => {
     // Do something here!
     console.log('Testing click!');
  }

  render() {
    const children = response.children;

    return React.createElement(response.component, null,
      React.createElement(children[0].component, null, children[0].text),
      React.createElement(children[1].component, {
        ...children[1],
        onClick: this.onImageClick, // <-- Adds the click event
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

You might want to create an utility that dynamically walks through the response object and creates all the components that you need.

Comment: Unfortunately in my particular case, the Wordpress API returns full HTML blocks as opposed to parsed JSON elements... Therefore I think I'm forced to use Regex ;( Thanks for your attempt!

Answer (score 0):

I think a more idiomatic React way of doing this would be to refactor this into a component, replete with it's own `onClick` handler, and then insert your image URL via props. Something like

```
class MyImg extends React.Component {
  onClick() {
    // foo
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onClick}>
        <h1>{this.props.foo}</h1>
        <img src={this.props.imgSrc} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, I would LOVE to do that, but I don't know if I can. So to give you more detail, I'm using wordpress as my backend. Then using the wordpress API, I'm receiving a pre populated HTML string. I need to somehow parse it and inject my onClick handler in there. Does that make sense? Or maybe I'm missing your point :(

Comment: If you need to do some kind of regex parsing, I'd recommend using that to extract data out of your HTML string and using it React-style, as opposed to attempting to inject the handler. Least hacky alternative IMO

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely keep that in mind. I'm kind of hoping there's a solution involving REACTDOM or something :)